# Quando uso reverse() a saída é "None"

Tags: python

```
continua = 'p'
valores = [] 
cinco = 5 
while continua != 'n':
   valores.append(int(input('Digite um numero')))
   continua = input('Deseja continuar? [S/N]').lower().strip()[0]
   
   if continua =='n':
       print('Fechando programa')
       break
   if continua =='s':
       print('Continuando o programa.')
    

print(f'Foram digitados {len(valores)} valores \n Sendo eles {valores.reverse()} \n ', 'Não teve 5 na lista.'if not 5 in valores else 'Teve 5 na lista.' )

Quanto tento rodar esse codigo na parte do print 'sendo eles' ele me retorna ' none ' 
ficando assim 
' Foram digitados 3 valores
 Sendo eles None
  Não teve 5 na lista.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o reverse antes do print

```
continua = 'p'
valores = [] 
cinco = 5 

while continua != 'n':
   valores.append(int(input('Digite um numero')))
   continua = input('Deseja continuar? [S/N]').lower().strip()[0]
   
   if continua =='n':
       print('Fechando programa')
       break
   if continua =='s':
       print('Continuando o programa.')

    
valores.reverse()

print(f'Foram digitados {len(valores)} valores \n Sendo eles {valores} \n ', 'Não teve 5 na lista.'if not 5 in valores else 'Teve 5 na lista.' )
```